# Set priority for Cordova Android notification?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

When setting an [Android notification](https://material.google.com/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-settings-priority), the priority level is significant.

When using Apache Cordova, how do I set the priority? The main documentation about [Cordova notifications](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/index.html#navigatornotificationalert) doesn't mention anything about setting priorities.

I need the local code in the app to put up a "normal" Android notification. How is that done?

---

***Edit***... I've since found the [plugin by katzer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) that is better than the 'core' plugins. It still doesn't have priorities, but I can live it with.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add property priority:{number between -2 to 2} on notification.

example:

```
 cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
            id: 1,
            title: 'title',
            text: 'text',
            icon: 'iconfile.png',
            priority: 1,
            sound: null,
            at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 10)
        });
```

hope this will help u.